# How to call objects (many to many relationships)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on Rails project. I want to call `join_events`. But the error occurs. I want only people joined events or the organizer to see event page.

```
uninitialized constant User::JoinEvent
```

**events_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @event = Event.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
  unless @event.user === current_user || current_user.join_events.include?(@event)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :join_events, dependent: :destroy, source: :tickets
end
```

**ticket.rb**

```
class Ticket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the class for which the association is made ( here Ticket) otherwise it will look for a JoinEvent class :

```
class_name: 'Ticket'
```

However, are you sure that

```
 current_user.join_events.include?(@event)
```

Allows you to search directly for an event?

Because join_events is just the tickets associated with the user, which themselves are linked to an event. You'll have to request on the joint events (tickets), then on the associated event I think.

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't... Although the user has tickets for the event but he couldn't see the page.

Comment: Could you try : current_user.join_events.where(event: {id: @event }).present?

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is `nil`. It seems that you access this page as a not logged-in user. You need to ensure that the page is not accessible without logging in.

Rails by default generates relation class based on its name. For `:join_events`, it'll be searching for `JoinEvent` class. You need to add `class_name` to you relationship definition:

```
has_many :join_events, dependent: :destroy, source: :tickets, class_name: 'Ticket'
```

I also guess that you can drop `source: :tickets`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated an error message.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. But I couldn't. The events are related to the users via tickets (many to many). So I have to define the event not tickets.